# Custom Typescript Definition for react-boostrap-typeahead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom Typescript definition for [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead). So far, here's what I have based on the documentation:

```
// Custom made typings based on exampes: https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead

declare namespace ReactBootstrapTypeahead {
    import React = __React;

    // Input
    class ReactBootstrapTypeahead extends React.Component<ReactBootstrapTypeaheadProps, any> {

    }

    interface ReactBootstrapTypeaheadProps extends React.HTMLProps<ReactBootstrapTypeahead> {
        align?: string;
        allowNew?: boolean;
        defaultSelected?: any[];
        disabled?: boolean;
        emptyLabel?: string;
        labelKey?: string;
        maxHeight?: number;
        minLength?: number;
        multiple?: boolean;
        name?: string;
        newSelectionPrefix?: string;
        onBlur?(): any;
        onChange?(): any;
        onInputChange?(): any;
        options: any[];
        paginateResults?: number;
        paginationText?: string;
        placeholder?: string;
        renderMenuItemChildren?(): any;
    }
}

declare module 'react-bootstrap-typeahead' {
    export = ReactBootstrapTypeahead;
}
```

I'm getting a couple errors when I try to use the component:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I'm new to this whole Typescript definitions thing so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to publish this to https://www.npmjs.com/~types ?

Answer (score 3):

When you are writing a declaration file for a library, it is strongly advised to try to wrap everything in a modular declaration file instead of a global declaration.

I'd first pull in a modular declaration file of react (`typings install react --save`).

Then I'd change your declaration file to specifically pull in the typings from react.

**custom-typings/react-bootstrap-typeahead**

```
declare module 'react-bootstrap-typeahead' {
  import React = require('react')
  interface ReactBootstrapTypeaheadProps extends React.HTMLProps<ReactBootstrapTypeahead> {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }
  class ReactBootstrapTypeahead extends React.Component<ReactBootstrapTypeaheadProps, any> {
  }
  export = ReactBootstrapTypeahead
}
```

Anywhere in your project, this should compile just fine

```
 import ReactTypeahead = require('react-bootstrap-typeahead')
```

Comment: For more details on implementation, see [this issue](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/116#issuecomment-267625659) and the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/pull/128). But basically what @Pelle noted above.